# Where to make feature requests for the Ubuntu MATE Team

Tags: development, ubuntu-mate

I want to remove the Ubuntu MATE Welcome program, this is not useful as this is a single user installation. And no new or guest users will use the computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the best place to take your request is the [Ubuntu MATE community forum](https://ubuntu-mate.community/), specifically the [feedback thread](https://ubuntu-mate.community/c/feedback). There are a lot of feature requests there.

Meanwhile, you know you can tell Welcome not to open by **unchecking** the box bottom right of it **Open Welcome when I Log On**:

[image]

You'll never see it again :)

Don't try to remove it with apt though:

```
$ sudo apt remove ubuntu-mate-welcome -s
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED
  ubuntu-mate-desktop ubuntu-mate-welcome
        ^^^
```

Comment: Yes, I unchecked that, I expressed my views on this on launchpad but it is private since I tagged as security issue. Mainly because this app offers applications out of the official repo's and it is being enforced to be present with the MATE desktop environment to all users. I haven't noticed this behavior is the past in any Ubuntu based distro.

Comment: And it doesn't have Source package

Comment: I figured you knew that, but I mentioned it to make the answer more useful to others... See my first sentence for where to take the request

Comment: Forget it I'll get an account when I'm a developer. I think the Launchpad team is the appropriate step. This really starts ringing bells.

Answer (score 2):

Asking how to achieve something in MATE - like disabling a feature - should be done at the forum, but since your title has "feature requests", I thought I'd address that for future readers. Definitely do NOT ask for new features, or improvements on current features, in the general **Support & Help Requests** section of the forum - your pleas will fall on deaf ears, because it's simply not the place to post development requests (it's a user help forum, after all). There *is* a **[Development Discussion](https://ubuntu-mate.community/c/development-discussion/)** section at the community forum, as well as **[Thoughts & Feedback](https://ubuntu-mate.community/c/feedback)**, but since the developers may not even be looking there, I would suggest the project's **[Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-mate)** page, and their **[GitHub](https://github.com/ubuntu-mate)** one, too. You will often see requests in **Thoughts & Feedback** being answered with *"please file this feature request  at GitHub"*, so it's worth having an account there if you want to get active in making the distribution better.